# React + MaterialUI display JPEG stream with authentification

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, basic-authentication, mjpeg

I want to display several  JPEG video streams on my website. Currently I use the `<CardMedia>` component from material-ui to display the video:

`<CardMedia  component='img' image={http://usr:pw@/url.com/faststream.jpg} />`

This works fine unless you use browser like chrome, which deprecated (I know for a good reason, but the app is only applied locally) the `user:password` syntax for basic auth in the url. A possible solution for this problem is to expose an additional endpoint and redirect to the JPEG stream.

Since my backend is already throttling with other things and I have several JPEG streams to redirect, I would love to grab the JPEG stream directly in the frontend. Is there any solution to achieve this with reasonable performance?